# calculate percentage of individual categories in MDX

Tags: mdx, ssas-2008

[image]I want to calculate percentage of individual Categories, Here is my mdx code.

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Individual_Total] AS ([DIM RATING STRINGS].[LABEL]*[Measures].AGG_RATING Count])

 SELECT
  NONEMPTY { 
   [Measures].[AGG_RATING Count],[Measures].[Individual_Total]
      } ONColumns,

  ([DIM STRUCTURE].[PARENT CODE].&[M01]&[M]:[DIM STRUCTURE].[PARENT CODE].&[M11]&[M],
  [DIM TAILORING].[TAILORING_LABEL].[TAILORING_LABEL],
  {[DIM RATING STRINGS].[LABEL].[LABEL],[DIM RATING STRINGS].[LABEL]}

  ) onrows


 FROM [Cube]
```

Here is the output

In this output we have 4 categories like ""External Drivers ,stretegy,Business operation and governance.

I need to calculate percentage of different color with in the same category.
For example if we take "External Drivers" then Calculation should be like 
amber = 15/28 * 100, green = 5/28/*100 etc because 28 is the sum of external drivers.
 Please tell me how to do this thing in mdx.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can compare with my solution, it will give you the percent of the parent.

```
with 
member [Measures].[Percent of parent] as
([Measures].[Order Quantity]) /
([Product].[Product Categories].currentmember.parent,
[Measures].[Order Quantity])
,format_string = "percent"

SELECT
{([Measures].[Order Quantity]),
([Measures].[Percent of parent])} ON COLUMNS,
{[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].&[3]} *
{[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory].Members} *
{[Product].[Style].[Style].Members} *
{[Product].[Product].members}
ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

[image: Results]

I don´t know if i read your dimensions correctly but maybe your member should look something like:

```
with member [Measures].[Percent] as
 [Measures].[AGG_RATING Count] /
 ([DIM RATING STRINGS].[LABEL].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT,
  [Measures].[AGG_RATING Count])
 , format_string = "percent"
```